# Convert datetime format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this date time format

```
Mon May 01 2023 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

need to convert it to

```
2023-05-01T00:00:00
```

where time will be converted to 00:00:00 of each date time

Comment: `let dt = new Date('Mon May 01 2023 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)')
    dt.getFullYear() + '-' + (dt.getMonth() > 10 ? '' : '0' + dt.getMonth()) + (dt.getDate() > 10 ? '-' : '-0') + dt.getDate() + 'T00:00:00'`

Comment: Try this: 
`new Date("Mon May 01 2023 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)").toISOString().split(".")[0]` more info is here [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: @VivekanandVishvkarma i want it in Date type it is returning as string

Comment: @user3653474 Explain where you want to use that date time

Comment: @VivekanandVishvkarma I have `selectedDate: Date = new Date();` one variable declared which is binding to date picker there i have to bind this date format